# Which development model should be followed in solo projects?

Tags: architecture, workflow

If you're bolstering your portfolio, a freelancer or hobbyist, which development model should you follow in a solo project?

There's many development methodology's but which methodology works best for a solo project? or does the project itself define the model that would be best to use?

I see there's a lot of questions like "Which approach is best for x language in this solo project." but I don't see a broad standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a solo project you don't need to worry too much about the development methodology per se. Most development methodologies exist to co-ordinate a number of people or teams working on a product.

For solo projects trunk based development is all you need with releases of your software whenever there are new features to release.

If your software gains popularity and there are more contributors you can relook at it at that point.